# The half-life of a radio active substance is 7.94 days. Originally there is 230g of this substance. How long before only 15g remain?

Tags: calculus

I'am having problems solving this equation if someone can help me it would be greatly appreicated The half-life of a radio active substance is 7.94 days. Originally there is 230g of this substance. How long before only 15g remain?

Comment: Are you given a working definition of half-life?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

Use the fact that:

$$t_{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\ln(2)}{\lambda},$$

Where $t_{\frac{1}{2}}$ is the half-life of the substance and $\lambda$ is the decay constant for that substance.

Then use the solution to the differential equation for radioactive decay: $\frac{dN}{dt}=\lambda N$ to get:

$$N(t)=N_{0}e^{-\lambda t}$$

Use these equations to get your answer from the data you were given in the question.

Comment: so to begin.... I would do 7.49=in(20)/that symbol thing

Comment: To begin you would find the decay constant (by convention denoted $\lambda$) by re-arranging to get $$\lambda=t_{\frac{1}{2}}\times\ln(2)$$ In your case $t_{\frac{1}{2}}=7.94$.

Comment: alright thanks!

Comment: I have to go to work so I will finish this equation later if i get stuck do you think you can help me out? I would really appreciate it.